# Dealing with Facebook JSON with AJAX

Tags: json, facebook, jquery

I'm trying to retrieve details about a facebook event that a user enters the url for.

Basically, the user enters the url for the event eg. https://www.facebook.com/event.php?eid=102036779889416
Then the resultant JSON formatted information would be assigned to variables and passed into appropriate form values, its just an auto populate feature to make things simpler on my site.

Now I've got the form to pass the url to the file, I'm using getjson

```
$.getJSON("getevent.php?event="+event,function(data)
```

But I dont know what to do with the return as, in the example I have been following, the json is formatted as such:

```
{"posts": 
[
{ 
"title":"9lessons | Programming Blog", 
"url":"http://9lessons.blogspot.com" 
}, 
{ 
"title":"jQuery and Ajax Demos Pard - 3", 
"url":"jquery-and-ajax-best-demos-part-3.html"
}, 
]
}
```

And can be output when it returns using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
{
$(document).ready(function()
{
$.getJSON("data.js",function(data)
{
$.each(data.posts, function(i,data)
{
var div_data =
"<div ><a href='"+data.url+"'>"+data.title+"</a></div>";
$(div_data).appendTo("#9lessonsLinks");
});
}
);
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

However, the Facebook returned JSON looks like this;

```
{
   "id": "188892631122084",
   "owner": {
      "name": "Gerard Alonso",
      "id": "742700474"
   },
   "name": "M.E.T.H.O.D. 11.6.2011",
   "description": "Yo! \n\nOld skool hip hop and other assorted jams at the Bodega. \n\nAll day jam with barbecue by Homemade, graffiti by Montana, Nottingham's best hip hop DJs and good vibes all round.\n\n\u00a33 entry all day and night, separate \u00a35 charge for Don't Flop rap battles upstairs http://www.facebook.com/event.php?eid=165044166891331.\n\n\nDJs line-up:\n\nTHE ELEMENTZ\nSQUIGZ\nBEATMASTER BILL\nSYNIC\nROOT ONE\nILLICIT & DESCRY\nADAM P\n+ more\n\n\nDuring the day:\n\n- Dont Flop rap battles upstairs (not included on the \u00a33 ticket price)\n- Mimm store >> http://tinyurl.com/3n8qltc\n- Jamaican BBQ (Homemade)\n- Funk and sunny hip hop in the downstairs bar\n\nIn the evening:\n\n- Old skool hip hop music upstairs along with plenty of mc's getting up in the mic\n- Drinks deals TBC\n- BBQ all day and night\n\n\nAny Mc's, dj's, breakers, graffiti artist  get in touch. \n\nPeace, love and hip hop.",
   "start_time": "2011-06-11T14:00:00",
   "end_time": "2011-06-12T03:30:00",
   "location": "The Bodega Social",
   "privacy": "OPEN",
   "updated_time": "2011-06-05T21:45:18+0000"
}
```

And as you can see it doesnt have a top level equivalent to 'posts' that I can use, so Im a bit stumped. Also I'm not sure how to output it on the file as I have this in the php file that the url is passed to:

```
$url = $_GET['event'];

parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ) );
$id = $eid;


$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id;

$json = file_get_contents($url,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_encode($json, false);


print_r($json_output);
```

Which seems wrong anyway, as the output is full of backslashes before every quotation

I know this is quite simple but I just cannot figure it out. What I want to do is assign each category to a variable to do something with it, but for now I'll just settle for outputting it first. I find AJAX so complicated because there seems to be about 10 ways to do the same thing.

Edit: I realised I dont need JSONdecode and just echo'd out $json. Firebug is seeing the JSON being generated fine but nothing is happening after adding this to the AJAX:

```
$.getJSON("getevent.php?event="+event,function(data)
{
var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('#arrData');
}
);
return false;
```

So I dont even know what im trying to fix now, as as far as I can make out ive done what the manual is telling me and the JSON is correct?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I think the JSON you are yrying to use is for a list of posts. The second JSON extract looks like the right one (i.e. an event object).

Comment: No, i think you have misread. The first one is the one used in the example I am following. The second json is the one I want to use. I know it is the correct one, I just dont know how to use it.

Comment: It should work fine. I have tried the JSON extract with your JavaScript code and it does display all the event properties in a list. Have you checked the value received by getJSON e.g., window.alert(data) ?

Comment: I get [object Object] in the alert box?

Comment: It just randomly started working, I dont know what I changed but it outputs perfectly fine now. Thanks